# update the state slice in redux lwc from the action payload

Tags: react-redux, lwc

below is my code to update the state.customer slice. However when this runs, I see that the next state is not updated with the payload dispatched from the action. can some one please point out what I'm missing?

### reducer:

```
const initialState1 = {"customer":{}};

const customer = (state = initialState1, action) => {
    console.log('state:', state);
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INIT_CUSTOMER_INFO':
            return {
               ...state,
               customer: action.payload
            }
        case 'UPD_CUSTOMER_INFO':
            console.log(action);
            return { ...customer, firstname: action.firstname }
        default: return state;
    }
}

export default customer;
```

### action

```
export const initCustomer = customer => {
    return {
          type: 'INIT_CUSTOMER_INFO',
          payload : customer
    }
}
```

### dispatch from LWC

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import { connect } from 'c/connect';
import { updateCustomer, initCustomer } from 'c/actions';
import getJSONData from '@salesforce/apex/RGClass.getCartSummary';

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    customer: state.customer
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
    initCustomer : customer => dispatch(initCustomer(customer)),
    updateCustomer : customer => dispatch(updateCustomer(customer))
})

export default class DigiForm extends LightningElement {
@track firstname;
showfirstname;

connectedCallback() {
    //add the hook
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(this);//connects the
    //api call
    getJSONData()
        .then(result => {
            console.log('result:',result);
            this.initCustomer(result);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
onContinue = () => {
    let fn = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input').value;

    console.log('firstname:', fn);
    this.updateCustomer({ firstname : fn});
    if(fn != null){
        this.showfirstname = true;
    }
}
}
```

Tried a couple of options but none worked. any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: These two parts of your code aren't connected in any way that is apparent from what you've shown. You'll need to show also how you're dispatching the action, and how you're creating your store.

Comment: @ChadS. Thanks for your response. Ive added the LWC code that dispatches the event